# Didn't get Vox Populi Badge

Tags: support, badges

I voted 40 times today (main), but I still don't have a Vox Popluli Badge. What's going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some badges are awarded instantly, others are awarded after Stack Exchange does it's daily processing. I wouldn't worry until it's been at least 24 hours after you've earned a badge, especially one like Vox Popluli that's based off of a daily count.

Comment: I've got it now ;)